# Killing A Process in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm just trying to explore the intricacies of C# and I wanted to make a simple program that would just kill a process. Yes I know, that is what Task Manager is for but this is supposed to be a learning experience, this is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace endProcess
{
    class Program
    {

        private Process GetaProcess(string processname)
        {
            Process[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname);

            if (aProc.Length > 0)
                return aProc[0];

            else return null;
        }
        string selectProcess = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What process do you want to kill?");
            selectProcess = Console.ReadLine();
            Process myprc = Call GetAProcess(selectProcess);
            myprc.Kill();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue comes where I made the comment. It says there should be a semicolon after GetAProcess and I have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is C#, not T-SQL: remove "Call" before GetAProcess.

Comment: Also, you should [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) any `Process` object you get a reference to, including those in `aProc`.

Comment: I'm guessing at VB6.  Reading an introductory book on C# programming is essential here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't say `Call GetaProcess` you simply say `GetaProcess`

The line should look like this : `Process myprc = GetaProcess(selectProcess);`

Comment: Method names are case-sensitive too. So it should be `GetaProcess`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, always miss the little things :p